# Symfony 1.4 - Force symfony to stop execution before reaching post validators

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am creating a lost password form in symfony 1.4, and keep running into an issue where the post validators are being called even if the widget constraints are failing.

Snippet:

```
$this->validatorSchema['email_address'] = new sfValidatorEmail(
    array(
        'max_length'    => 254,  // http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696&eid=1690
        'min_length'    => 4,
        'required'      => true,
        'trim'          => true
    ),
    array(
        'invalid'       => 'Email address entered is malformed',
        'max_length'    => 'Email Address cannot contain more than %max_length% characters',
        'min_length'    => 'Email Address must be at least %min_length% characters',
        'required'      => 'Please enter an email address'
    )
);

$this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'emailValidate'))));
$this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'throttleCheck'))));
```

The problem is the 'emailValidate' callback assumes a well formed email address has been entered, something like a@b.com, but if I enter garbage, like 'fdadfaa', the form still proceeds to try to execute the post validator, when it shouldn't. There is no reason to issue a query if the data is no good.

I [found](http://symfonyexperts.com/question/show/id/131) a 'halt_on_error' flag which can be passed to a schema validator constructor, but didn't work for me. Anyone else cross this bridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony is a wild ride... was able to get it to work using this:

```
$this->validatorSchema['email_address'] = new sfValidatorAnd(
    array(
        new sfValidatorEmail(
            array(
                'max_length'    => 254,  // http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696&eid=1690
                'min_length'    => 4,
                'required'      => true,
                'trim'          => true
            ),
            array(
                'invalid'       => 'Email address entered is malformed',
                'max_length'    => 'Email Address cannot contain more than %max_length% characters',
                'min_length'    => 'Email Address must be at least %min_length% characters'                        
            )
        ),
        new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'emailValidate'))),
        new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'throttleCheck')))
    ),
    array('halt_on_error' => true),
    array('required' => 'Please enter an email address')
);
```

The only problem here, the postValidators are tied directly to the email field, so you have to change any references from `$values['email']` to `$values`. But it does seem to work in ceasing execution flow before hitting the post validators.